What's an Unethical Drug to Limit Anger in a Dystopic Setting
I am writing a dystopia story where anyone who expresses anger or rebels against the government gets labeled mentally ill and given drugs to make them complacent. One character, lets call him John Doe, starts off as a cop who is taking a drug daily because he was 'diagnosed' while a child. Eventually, he joins the rebellion against the evil government. All pretty standard stuff.
The twist is that John Doe stops taking the drug after joining, and he gets worse. It ends up that unlike 99% of everyone else forced to take the drugs, he legitimately has a mental illness. The drug designed to keep everyone in order was actually treating his condition. To make this story work, I need to do an absolutely mountain of research since I'll be writing about a mental illness I don't have. Did some searching and it seems a good condition to give John Doe is Intermediate Explosive Disorder (see page 466 of the DSM-5).
The problem I am having is I do not know enough pharmacology to figure out what drug he should have been taking, the side effects, and withdrawal symptoms. Although IED is sometimes treated with medications, such as fluoxetine, those medications that is really what I am looking for. The side effects are too minor (1, 2). I could just make something up, or exaggerate the side effect of fluoxetine, but I would rather base this aspect of the story in realism.
EDIT:
This question kind of blew up in a way I wasn't expecting. I am going to include a lot more information about my story and worldbuilding technique because a lot of people have expressed concerns that are not really applicable. I didn't do this originally because I viewed this info as irrelevant to the question being asked.
John Doe's story is going to have 3 main acts. First, he is on the medication and holding down a job and is not committing any crimes, but has no meaningful social relationships and frequently drinks to deal with stress. The dystopic society considers him 'cured' even though his quality of life is very poor, because it only cares about its citizens being economically productive and socially non-disruptive. That view of mental illness exists today, as shown by Rob Ford's statement, "If I’m an addict, I could not show up to work every single day." In act 2 John joins the rebellion and gets sober, but he has anger-filled episodes due to IED. In act 3, another rebel derives cognitive behavioral therapy from first principles and helps John Doe though it. This leads to him actually being able to tell when an episode is coming on and calm himself. In the end he has a much higher quality of life, with meaningful relationships and a supportive social group.
For acts 2 and 3 I need to know what about IED and CBT, respectively. I have been able to find a lot of information on both after a little bit of research, so I should be fine looking up more specifics as I need them. However, for acts 1 and 2 also need to decide the medication's side effects and withdrawal symptoms. That information for drugs is actually pretty easy to look up, but you need to know the name of the drug first. I tried looking up information for SSRIs such as fluoxetine, but the results were not what I needed. For completely understandable reasons, modern medical practice is to not prescribe medications with debilitating and dramatic side effects for illnesses that can be treated with therapy.
Now, a couple of people have proposed just making up a drug and adding whatever side effects I want. I can understand why they would suggest that, but that is not how I like to worldbuild central elements of my stories. For example, when I was writing about aliens, I did a lot of reading on allometry and life history. When I realized my squirrel-sized sapient aliens would only live a couple decades, I decided to ignore that and gave them a longer lifespan that were still shorter than humanity's. Importantly, that was an informed decision. I knew the scientifically correct answer, but compromised it for the sake of the story. Along the same lines, I would prefer to know if a drug fitting my narrative requirements exists and base my fictional drug on it. If it does not exist, then I will make something up.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Ethics and the setting don't matter. Drug to Limit Anger? : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typical_antipsychotic

Haloperidol
I gotta go with a classic, here; Haloperidol, also known as Haldol.
A bit of history as to why this would fit your use case; it's been used for exactly this before.
This was used by the Rajneeshee cult in Oregon back in the 80's. They spiked the beer with it and distributed said beer for free to the vast numbers of homeless people they'd been importing from around America for complicated political reasons.
The community in question started off with a shared intention; following their leader in their spiritual journey. There wasn't all that much conflict within that core group.
However, as part of a plan to overwhelm the local residents in local politics, to incorporate as a city and subsume the already-present small town of Antelope, they brought in a lot of street people with free bus tickets and offers of beer, food, shelter and free love.
This worked for their plan, but came with a price. Suddenly the core group found themselves overwhelmed by a large number of street people uninterested in following the cult leader or their rules, and often coming with pre-existing issues with drugs and mental health.
In a bid to keep calm and control within the commune, the beer was spiked with Haldol to make people calmer and more compliant.

"In a 2013 comparison of fifteen antipsychotics in schizophrenia, chlorpromazine demonstrated mild-standard effectiveness. It was 13% more effective than lurasidone and iloperidone, approximately as effective as ziprasidone and asenapine, and 12–16% less effective than haloperidol, quetiapine, and aripiprazole." .... 'I don't like seeing the patients disturbing their rooms like this. See that she takes her thorazine.'

I am going to go with an antipsychotic drug like haloperidol, but will make up a brand name and will never say the exact chemical name. If it is good enough for crazy cultist and the KGB, its good enough for me.

I used to take this and it almost turns you into a sort of emotionless zombie so pretty spot on.

Good Worldbuilding and the Law
Good worldbuilding is as much about knowing when to chase the rabbit of detail down the rabbit hole... and when not to.
Large, well-funded organizations own those real pharmaceuticals. They tend to be really touchy about people using the knowledge or reputation of their drugs in an unprofitable way. Unprofitable for them, of course. The point is, the other answers that have given you real drug names to work with (and they're great answers!) are also leading you to believe that you can actually use someone else's property with impunity.
The odds are nobody will notice or care. But let's pretend you get lucky and your story sells nationally. Make sure you have a good attorney. Of course, your publisher (if they're worth anything) will have forced you to change the name long before then.
Thou Shalt Not...
The basic rule of writing anything is "thou shalt not use someone else's stuff without their permission." There's a complicated gray area known as "fair use," but having been a publisher myself and being steeped in the laws and rules of that task, I assure you, there is no fair use when it comes to branded items, trademarks, and trade names. Period. Choose not to ask for permission at your own risk — and this really is one of those situations when asking for forgiveness isn't easier than asking for permission — because you're casting the medication in a bad light.
What should you do?

Use the knowledge you're gaining about real drugs to create (and I mean this) a fictional list of side effects. That list should be relevant to your story and should NOT simply be a list of side effects that are obviously associated with one product. A rose by any other name will get you sued just as quickly.

Use a medication name generator such as this one from RanGen to come up with a completely fictional name for your drug.


The unbridled quest for "realism" isn't worth losing your shirt
The modern quest to build worlds "as real as possible" has Real World consequences. The most common is that science is a harsh taskmaster and often leads to boring worlds. But in this case, the quest can lead you to a court room. If you think I've beaten a dead horse, believe me, I can't beat this horse enough. No two companies are the same. Some let the small stuff slide. Others act to protect their brands and trademarks ruthlessly. Considering that the name of the drug is nothing more than an aesthetic and using a "real drug" buys you nothing (really, it buys you absolutely nothing), please take my advice.
No matter how realistic you want to be, you're building a fictional world, and the reason you're doing that is the same reason phrases like, "the names have been changed to protect the innocent" exist. It has nothing to do with the innocent. It has everything to do with avoiding a lawsuit.

"Names have been changed to protect the author from innocent scumbags who really aren't all that innocent..."

Don't worry, I know its a bad idea to have a character look directly into the metaphorical camera and say, "The horrible drug the evil dystopic government uses to suppress us all is [insert trademarked name here]." I'll probably make up a name for the drug for my notes, but there is a 50/50 chance the drug doesn't get named in the story itself. The point I want readers to walk away with is what the drug does to John Doe, not the drug's name.

Very good point, hadn't thought of a regard for litigation as a part of W/B in this case.

There is a vast distance between unfairly presenting a trademarked brand and using a completely fictional drug.  To start with, every drug has an internationally recognized generic name.  More usefully, drugs usually belong to classes of compounds with related effects.  So instead of saying "Haldol" you could say "haloperidol", "a butyrophenone derivative", "an antipsychotic", and give it a fictitious trade name (almost everything has many trade names anyway).  Don't copy a list of side effects verbatim, but do portray what tardive dyskinesia is like and how people react to it.

I'd suggest Guanfacine. (α2-adrenergic receptor agonist).
It reduces anxiety, calms down the emotional centres of the brain - reducing sympathetic nervous system response, increasing prefrontal control of strong emotions and thought processes. (It's familiar to most US prescribers).
Side effects:
Abdominal pain, sedation, and QT prolongation, decreased appetite, nausea, dry mouth, urinary incontinence, and rashes, sleepiness, tiredness, headache, and stomach ache. The Big Pharma in your world is going to be kept busy making stuff to compensate for all that lot.
Withdrawal from cessation:
Headaches, agitation (which may manifest as aggression or panic) some hypertension (results of studies vary).
Frame Challenge:
What emerges from your protagonist is a new condition, never seen - because the whole population is doped-up all the time that it's never emerged. (Except the odd tail of previous rebels who exhibited such deplorable behaviour that was never able to be studied up close as they were assassinated or taken for rehabilitation and given high doses of whatever immediately).
There's also the deal that anything beyond the most basic psychiatry has been put on a backburner for a long time in your culture, many disease conditions characterized on our Earth have simply been forgotten or lost to the depredations of time in yours.
The advantage of this approach:
It gives you as a writer carte blanch to include whatever symptoms that drama and plot require without being constrained to current medical knowledge and pharmacology - though it certainly may be useful to make reference to various patterns of symptoms from familiar conditions as you go.
For parallels, see Soma, from Aldous Huxley's Brave New World.

It's a frame challenge, thus the divergence from the OP's plan. Your opinion regarding harmful stereotypes might be better expressed to the OP as they are the one writing the thing (bear in mind that this is fiction, not real life - but then again, maybe they're planning on trying to meet the particular standards of Disney which would suite you?). I'll edit my answer to add rebound characteristics.

yeah, I wrote almost identical comments on the original answer almost immediately after typing up the ones here, they're better there than under your answer so I deleted them here :)

The question calls for an unethical drug, but the one you suggest is widely considered ethical to prescribe.  If the story is written using this, it will have to dive deep into the politics surrounding this and similar drugs.  There certainly are people with ADHD who criticize how they've been treated, and the research can be done, but it's going to add a very heavy flavor to the whole story and would need to be pursued with exacting care.

I agree. It's been preying on my mind, the nature of medical ethics, disclosure, informed consent etc.. @MikeSerfas

Remember that drugs that mess with brain stuff can have quite unexpected effects. I take guanfacine (1mg, 3 times a day) off-label to treat Tourette's Syndrome. The only notable side effect I've ever had was increased harmful emotions, strong negative mood swings that make me snap at everyone around me and mope and be so uppity that I can't focus etc. whenever I increase the dose.
